# question about mysqli prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have basic question about mysqli prepared statements. For example, I want to execute a SELECT query, Should I do it like:

```
<?
$city = "Amersfoort";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($district);
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

In the above code, is bind_result also required? What exactly it does?

Also, do I need need to close mysqli connection after each query?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind_result` makes it so that when you iterate over the results of the query, the columns from the result set are automatically mapped to local variables.

For example, suppose you execute a query that returns a result set with three columns like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode, District FROM myCity";
```

You want to execute the query and do something with the results, let's say print them:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        printf("%s (%s,%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1], $row[2]);
    }
}
```

The "problem" with the above code is that `$row[0]` is not very descriptive. An alternative way is to use `bind_result`, which goes like this:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode, District FROM myCity";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $countryCode, $district);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("%s (%s,%s)\n", $name, $countryCode, $district);
    }
}
```

As you see, when using `bind_result` each time you call `fetch` the variables `$name`, `$countryCode`, `$district` are automatically populated with the values from the current result row. There are some details that you must ensure, read [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) for more info.

To answer your other question: you do not need to, and indeed you *must not* close the connection after each query (unless you know very well what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

`bind_result` assigns the variable to which data will be written. And you can keep the connection open. Just make sure you call `$stmt->fetch()` after `$stmt->bind_result($district);`

Check out Example #1 here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php